# Do I need to change the process priority or scheduler?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I'm running on Linux (Ubuntu). I have a process which contains 20 threads   All the threads have the same default priority & scheduler - 20. The default is not a RT scheduler. In my process all threads need to get the same priority 
(there is no thread which is more important than the other thread).
The other processes on the system are the OS processes .

I'm running on Intel I7 (quad core).
When using top I'm getting 140-150% CPU.
It seems that sometime the processes is choking without reason (some threads take longer to calculate some data)

I read some papers on priority & scheduler, but they didn't note if the change can harm the OS. Do I need to change the scheduler or priority of my process (threads)?

I didn't change yet, because I don't know if the change will harm the OS.

Comment: Why do you want to change the priority?  Are you having performance problems?  What is the system load?  How many processors do you have?  We don't have enough information.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Agree. It is unclear what you are asking. Do you need to change the process priority to achieve what???

Comment: If the threads have no I/O, maybe paging?  Do the threads process a lot of data?

Comment: some threads consumes more than 600mb, and some consumes ~60mb

Comment: Are you using the SCHED_RR round-robin scheduler?  All other threads at this priority will get to run before this thread is given the CPU once more.  The number of CPU cores would be useful to know.